# Find all *unique combinations* of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, permutation

I'd like to find all *unique combinations* of element positions of an array in JavaScript.

This is my array:

```
var places = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
```

I'd like to find the following combinations: [0,1], [0,2], [1,2].

Currently I have the functional but slightly unwieldy:

```
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < places.length; j++) {
        if ((j > i) && (j != i)) { 
            console.log(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a neater way to do it?

Comment: You don't need j!= i, every time you can reach it, it will evaluate false. any time j==i, j>i will evaluate to false, and the second condition will be skipped, along with rest of the 'if' statement. although, you could just use jodaka's suggestion and eliminate the if statement altogether

Comment: You're not comparing the values of the array atm. If you want to compare the value, use `places[i]` and `places[j]` instead of `i` and `j`.

Comment: @RobW - sorry, I wasn't clear, by unique combinations I mean unique combinations of array positions, not of the values in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start `j` at `i + 1` and eliminate your `if` condition.

Answer (score 9):

```
// from codecademy.com

var people = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "Dave", "Ed"];
var n = people.length;
var i, j;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
        console.log(people[i] + ", " +  people[j]);
    }
}

// output
Alice, Bob
Alice, Carol
Alice, Dave
Alice, Ed
Bob, Carol
Bob, Dave
Bob, Ed
Carol, Dave
Carol, Ed
Dave, Ed
```